# HTML in R not rendering when pasted

Tags: html, r, shiny

When rendering HTML tags in R, I get below output. That all tags in same line

Scenario 1

```
asd <- HTML("'<table><tr><td><b>COL1</b></td><td><b>COL2</b></td></tr></table>'")
asd
'<table><tr><td><b>COL1</b></td><td><b>COL2</b></td></tr></table>'
```

But when I render incorporate tags in HTML through paste function, I get in different line. Because, when I try to pass "asd" at some places after declaring in Scenario 2, its not working. But when I use "asd" after declaring in Scenario 1 , it is working

Scenario 2

```
asd <- HTML(paste0("'",tags$table(tags$tr(tags$td(tags$b("COL1")),tags$td(tags$b("COL2")))),"'"))
asd
'<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>COL1</b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b>COL2</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>'
```

Comment: Yeah. Also can we make Scenario 2 work ?

Comment: Where exactly are you using `asd` ? Can you show the code where it works and  where it fails?

Comment: Its a shiny application. Its  a callback function.                                                             ````                                                
 callback <- paste0("
        table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                                      var format = function(d) {
                                      return ",asd,"
                                      };                                                                                               
 ````